# WPF: Why can't I bind data?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window x:Class="GuessFigure.PlayingGameWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GuessFigure"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PlayingGame" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:GuessFigure.Model">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <c:Round x:Key="round"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <Binding Source=" {StaticResource round}" />
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbTime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,202,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="123,86,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="roundNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=Number}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Round.cs:

```
using GuessFigure.Model.Factory;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ninject.Planning.Bindings;

namespace GuessFigure.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 回合
    /// 
    /// 每回合限时30s，超时直接进入下一回合
    /// 
    /// 题目（数字）由FigureFactory类生产
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    class Round
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 回合数 
        /// 
        /// 一共五回合，每回合出一道猜数字的题目
        /// </summary>
        internal int Number { get; } = 1;

        /// <summary>
        /// 生产题目的工厂
        /// </summary>
        private FigureFactory figureFactory;

       [Inject]
       internal void  SetFigureFactory(FigureFactory figureFactory)
        {
            this.figureFactory = figureFactory;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 调用<see cref=">FigureFactory"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// 当前回合的题目。
        /// </returns>
        public int[] GetCurrentRoundFigures()
        {
            return figureFactory.Produce(Number);
        }
    }



    class RoundModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<FigureFactory>().To<FigureFactoryRound1>().When(request=>request.ParentRequest.Target.Type.GetField("number").Equals(1));
            Bind<FigureFactory>().To<FigureFactoryRound2>().When(request => request.Target.Type.GetField("number").Equals(2));
            Bind<FigureFactory>().To<FigureFactoryRound3>().When(request => request.Target.Type.GetField("number").Equals(3));
            Bind<FigureFactory>().To<FigureFactoryRound4>().When(request => request.Target.Type.GetField("number").Equals(4));
            Bind<FigureFactory>().To<FigureFactoryRound5>().When(request => request.Target.Type.GetField("number").Equals(5));

        }
    }


}
```

I want to bind class `Round`'s property `Number` to the second `TextBlock` in `Grid` and show it to user. However, there was nothing show after I made these code.

What's wrong in my code?

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Number'
>   property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1455514144)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Number; DataItem='String'
>   (HashCode=-1455514144); target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name='roundNumber'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Related question may help: [WPF/XAML Property not found on 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558379/wpf-xaml-property-not-found-on-object)

Comment: Can you check the output window for binding errors while running the application?

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas oh thanks, the output window was covered by other window so I did not find there was errors in output window.

Comment: `Number` isn't public and `Round` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (In case you want to update the value after the initial binding)

Comment: It does not need to implement INotifypropertChanged to read the value. Though it should be public as stated by @ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas see details in parentheses

Answer (score 1):

The property you bind to has to be public, your property is internal. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx).

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.

Also, this:

```
request.Target.Type.GetField("number").Equals(2)
```

Will not work since:

- `Number` has a capital N
- is a property
- `GetField("Number") returns a`FieldInfo` instance, not the value.

So what you can try is this:

```
request.Target.Type.GetProperty("number").GetValue(request.Target, null).Equals(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my code has multiple wrongs, and thank Maarten who indicated that

> The property you bind to has to be public, your property is internal.

However that was not enough and the problem was still there. I solved my problem at last, by remove the blank space before `{StaticResource round}` in `<Binding Source=" {StaticResource round}" />`.

Now the binding runs as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

- Your are trying to bind an attribute to a internal property which is wrong. The attribute can only bind to an **public property**.
- **Public property** is recommend to capitalize first letter.